# How to display server-side validation messages in the client side via react-query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-query

***Here is the Express route for the signup API call, It works as expected on the server-side but I  want to display these same validation messages in real-time when the user will put their credentials on the React client***

```
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Validate data before submission
    const { error } = registerValidation(
      req.body.username,
      req.body.firstname,
      req.body.lastname,
      req.body.email,
      req.body.password
    );
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    // Checking if username already exists
    const usernameExist = await database.query(
      "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=$1",
      [req.body.username]
    );
    if (usernameExist.rows[0])
      return res.status(400).send("Username already taken!");

    // Checking if email already exists
    const emailExist = await database.query(
      "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=$1",
      [req.body.email]
    );
    if (emailExist.rows[0])
      return res.status(400).send("Email already exists!");

    // Hash the password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    // Save the New User
    const newUser = await database.query(
      "INSERT INTO users(username, firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *",
      [
        req.body.username,
        req.body.firstname,
        req.body.lastname,
        req.body.email,
        hashedPassword,
      ]
    );
    res.json(newUser.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

***And here is my fetch POST request for signup.***

```
export const signUp = async (formData) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/signup`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      const errMsg = await res.text();
      throw new Error(errMsg);
    }

    await res.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};
```

***And here is the signup form using react-hook-form and react-query, the error message is displayed on the console but wanted to display it on screen in real-time while the user typing in the form without the need to submit the form to display those messages.***

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { joiResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/joi";
import Joi from "joi";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import { signUp } from "../API/API";

// Signup Form Validation
const schema = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
  firstname: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
  lastname: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
  email: Joi.string()
    .min(6)
    .required()
    .email({ tlds: { allow: false } }),
  password: Joi.string().min(6).required(),
});

const SignupForm = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ resolver: joiResolver(schema) });

  const mutation = useMutation(signUp);

  const history = useHistory();

  // To submit data on server
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    // const res = await mutation.mutate(data);
    // console.log(res);
    await mutation.mutate(data);
    history.push("/");
  };

  console.log(errors);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Sign up</h3>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Username"
          {...register("username", { required: true, min: 3 })}
        />
        <p>{errors.username?.message}</p>

        <br />

        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstname"
          placeholder="First Name"
          {...register("firstname", { required: true, min: 3 })}
        />
        <p>{errors.firstname?.message}</p>
        <br />

        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastname"
          placeholder="Last Name"
          {...register("lastname", { required: true, min: 3 })}
        />
        <p>{errors.lastname?.message}</p>
        <br />

        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          {...register("email", {
            required: true,
            min: 6,
            pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i,
          })}
        />
        <p>{errors.email?.message}</p>
        <br />

        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          {...register("password", { required: true, min: 6 })}
        />
        <p>{errors.password?.message}</p>
        <br />

        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignupForm;
```

Comment: what does "in real time" mean please? If you want to get it after each keystroke, you'll need to likely make an additional request (on each keystroke) to the backend that does the validation

Comment: suppose the user is putting his info in one input field and there's some validation error so the error message will display instantly, he doesn't have to fill the full form and click on the submit button to see the error messages. This is what I mean.

Comment: Okay and is this error coming from the frontend or the backend?

Comment: validations are set on the server, it should come from there, check the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your syntax and all but did you check onError property?.

```
  const { mutate } = useMutation(signUp, {
onSuccess: () => {
     alert("successful");
},
onError: () => {
  setStatus("there is an error");
},
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it'll not work. here you set the error message on the client side but the problem is to get error messages from the server-side.

Comment: there onSuccess field if you get data in like {data:[], status:"error from backend" }, then you can show in :: alert(data?.status);